# Checkbox filter is not working in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have apply the checkbox filter using that the function data is filtered but after loading the whole page  array content is not display,the data is display only check 1 condition if the user check the checkbox,how to solve this?

```js
/**
  - @Copyright Notice:
  - @(#)
  - @Type: Controller
  - @For: seller_dashboard_controller.js used for  seller_dashboard.jsp page
  - @Description: 
 */

bobApp.controller("buyerDashboardProfileController", ['$scope', 'BuyerDashboardService', function($scope, BuyerDashboardService) {
 
 /**
  * @Summary:getIntermediaryOnBuyerDashboard, to get the connected intermediary List.
  * @param:   callback
  * @return:  callback(response) .
  * @Description: 
  */
 $scope.connetedIntermediary = [];
 
 //Defining function for $scope.getConnectedIntermediary in service 
 $scope.getConnectedIntermediary = function() {
  //used for get connected intermediary
  var data = {
    buyerUserTypeKeyId  : Number(AUTH.userTypeKeyId),
    userTypeRel         : "buyer",
    reqFromUserType     : "buyer",
    reqToUserType       : "intermediary"
  };
  BuyerDashboardService.getBuyerDashboard(function(response) {
   if(response != null) {
    if(response.data.isSuccess) {
     $scope.connetedIntermediary = response.data.userRelationDto;
    }
   }
  },data)
 };
 $scope.getConnectedIntermediary();
 

 /**
  * @Summary:connectedSeller, to get the connected connected SellerList.
  * @param:   callback
  * @return:  callback(response) .
  * @Description: 
  */
 $scope.connectedSeller = [];
 //Defining function for $scope connetedSeller in service 
 $scope.getConnectedSeller = function() {
  //used for get connected seller
  var data = {
    buyerUserTypeKeyId  : Number(AUTH.userTypeKeyId),
    userTypeRel         : "buyer",
    reqFromUserType     : "buyer",
    reqToUserType       : "seller"
  };
  BuyerDashboardService.getBuyerDashboard(function(response) {
   if(response != null) {
    if(response.data.isSuccess) {
     $scope.connectedSeller = response.data.userRelationDto;
    }
   }
  },data)
 };
 $scope.getConnectedSeller(); 
 
 /**
  * @Summary:filterCityList, to get the filtered cityList.
  * @param:   callback
  * @return:  callback(response) .
  * @Description: 
  */
 
   $scope.filterCityList = [];
 //Defining function for includeCity for received the city after click on the checkbox 
  $scope.includeCity = function(city) {
  var i = $.inArray(city, $scope.filterCityList);
    if (i > -1) {
     $scope.filterCityList.splice(i, 1);
    } else {
     $scope.filterCityList.push(city);
   }
  }
  
 //Defining  cityFilter function for filter the city for the connectedSeller
 $scope.cityFilter = function(connectedSeller) {
  if ($scope.includeCity.length > 0) {
   if ($.inArray(connectedSeller.city, $scope.filterCityList) < 0)
    return;
   }
  return connectedSeller;
 }
 }
]);
```

```html
<div id="seller" class="userTab" style="display:none">
   <div class="w3-col m7 l9">
    <div class="w3-container w3-card-2 w3-white w3-hover-light-grey" 
     ng-repeat="seller in connectedSeller.sellerDtos | filter:cityFilter" 
     style="margin:0 0px 0px 0px; padding:0px;">
     <img src="{{seller.userTypeDto.imageURL !=null ? seller.userTypeDto.imageURL : '/static/assets/img/image_placeholder.jpg'}}" 
      class="w3-border w3-padding w3-margin-right pull-left userImg">
     <div class="">
      <h5 class="w3-opacity w3-padding-top">
       <b>{{seller.firmName}}</b>
      </h5>
      <h6 class="w3-text-teal">
       <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>
       {{seller.personName}}
       <span class="w3-tag w3-teal w3-round w3-small">
        {{seller.userTypeDto.userType}}
       </span>
      </h6>
      <p>
       <span ng-if="seller.userTypeDto.email">
        Email - {{seller.userTypeDto.email}} |
       </span>
       <span ng-if="seller.userTypeDto.phoneNumber"> 
        Contact Number - {{seller.userTypeDto.phoneNumber}} |
       </span>
       <span ng-if="seller.city"> 
        City - {{seller.city}} |
       </span>
       <span ng-if="seller.state"> 
        State- {{seller.state}} 
       </span>
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
/**
  - @Copyright Notice:
  - @(#)
  - @Type: Controller
  - @For: seller_dashboard_controller.js used for  seller_dashboard.jsp page
  - @Description: 
 */

bobApp.controller("buyerDashboardProfileController", ['$scope', 'BuyerDashboardService', function($scope, BuyerDashboardService) {
 
 /**
  * @Summary:getIntermediaryOnBuyerDashboard, to get the connected intermediary List.
  * @param:   callback
  * @return:  callback(response) .
  * @Description: 
  */
 $scope.connetedIntermediary = [];
 
 //Defining function for $scope.getConnectedIntermediary in service 
 $scope.getConnectedIntermediary = function() {
  //used for get connected intermediary
  var data = {
    buyerUserTypeKeyId  : Number(AUTH.userTypeKeyId),
    userTypeRel         : "buyer",
    reqFromUserType     : "buyer",
    reqToUserType       : "intermediary"
  };
  BuyerDashboardService.getBuyerDashboard(function(response) {
   if(response != null) {
    if(response.data.isSuccess) {
     $scope.connetedIntermediary = response.data.userRelationDto;
    }
   }
  },data)
 };
 $scope.getConnectedIntermediary();
 

 /**
  * @Summary:connectedSeller, to get the connected connected SellerList.
  * @param:   callback
  * @return:  callback(response) .
  * @Description: 
  */
 $scope.connectedSeller = [];
 //Defining function for $scope connetedSeller in service 
 $scope.getConnectedSeller = function() {
  //used for get connected seller
  var data = {
    buyerUserTypeKeyId  : Number(AUTH.userTypeKeyId),
    userTypeRel         : "buyer",
    reqFromUserType     : "buyer",
    reqToUserType       : "seller"
  };
  BuyerDashboardService.getBuyerDashboard(function(response) {
   if(response != null) {
    if(response.data.isSuccess) {
     $scope.connectedSeller = response.data.userRelationDto;
    }
   }
  },data)
 };
 $scope.getConnectedSeller(); 
 
 /**
  * @Summary:filterCityList, to get the filtered cityList.
  * @param:   callback
  * @return:  callback(response) .
  * @Description: 
  */
 
   $scope.filterCityList = [];
 //Defining function for includeCity for received the city after click on the checkbox 
  $scope.includeCity = function(city) {
  var i = $.inArray(city, $scope.filterCityList);
    if (i > -1) {
     $scope.filterCityList.splice(i, 1);
    } else {
     $scope.filterCityList.push(city);
   }
  }
  
 //Defining  cityFilter function for filter the city for the connectedSeller
 $scope.cityFilter = function(connectedSeller) {
  if ($scope.includeCity.length > 0) {
   if ($.inArray(connectedSeller.city, $scope.filterCityList) < 0)
    return;
   }
  return connectedSeller;
 }
 }
]);
```

```html
<div id="seller" class="userTab" style="display:none">
   <div class="w3-col m7 l9">
    <div class="w3-container w3-card-2 w3-white w3-hover-light-grey" 
     ng-repeat="seller in connectedSeller.sellerDtos | filter:cityFilter" 
     style="margin:0 0px 0px 0px; padding:0px;">
     <img src="{{seller.userTypeDto.imageURL !=null ? seller.userTypeDto.imageURL : '/static/assets/img/image_placeholder.jpg'}}" 
      class="w3-border w3-padding w3-margin-right pull-left userImg">
     <div class="">
      <h5 class="w3-opacity w3-padding-top">
       <b>{{seller.firmName}}</b>
      </h5>
      <h6 class="w3-text-teal">
       <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>
       {{seller.personName}}
       <span class="w3-tag w3-teal w3-round w3-small">
        {{seller.userTypeDto.userType}}
       </span>
      </h6>
      <p>
       <span ng-if="seller.userTypeDto.email">
        Email - {{seller.userTypeDto.email}} |
       </span>
       <span ng-if="seller.userTypeDto.phoneNumber"> 
        Contact Number - {{seller.userTypeDto.phoneNumber}} |
       </span>
       <span ng-if="seller.city"> 
        City - {{seller.city}} |
       </span>
       <span ng-if="seller.state"> 
        State- {{seller.state}} 
       </span>
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```